# Merging two Max heap which are complete Binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

Let H1 and H2 be two complete binary trees that are heaps as well. Assume H1 and H2 are max-heaps, each of size n .Design and analyse an efficient algorithm to merge H1 and H2 to a new max-heap H of size 2n.

==========================================================================

Approach - First copy the two arrays of H1 and H2 into a new array of size 2n...then apply build heap operation to get H...Time complexity=O(2n)=O(n), but doesn't need we need to apply Max heapify after building the heap? So, where's O(logn) time considered for that.

===================================================================

Another approach says merging two max heaps takes O(n+m) time. Now, what's correct and why no one is caring for Max Heapify?

Comment: What is  a difference between `apply build heap operation to get H` and `Max heapify`?

Comment: `copy the two arrays of H1 and H2` Is *each heap is represented as an array of nodes with relationships specified by relative position* part of the task specification? If not: may *H1* and *H2* be modified/"destroyed"?

Answer (score 2):

MaxHeapify operation takes O(logn) time.
 In Build Heap Operation, we need to call MaxHeapify n times. Therefore it seems that total complexity of build heap operation is O(nlogn)

But it is not correct. Actually build heap operation takes only O(n) time.You can refer this link to get idea about it.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-of-building-a-heap/

Hence it takes O(2n) => O(n) time complexity to build new heap H of size 2n.

If you consider two max heaps of size m and n, it takes O(m+n) time complexity to build new heap of size m+n.